# How to evaluate the integral without using integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

How can we evaluate the following integral by using substitution rule only?

$$\int \sqrt{\frac{x^2 - 2x}{x^6}}\,dx$$

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Context is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $z=\sqrt{\dfrac{x-2}{x}}.$ Then
$x-2=xz^2,\ $ and $$x=\dfrac{2}{1-z^2}, \ \  x-2 = \dfrac{2z^2}{1-z^2}, \ \ dx = \dfrac{4z}{(1-z^2)^2}\,dz,$$
$$\dfrac{x^2-2x}{x^6}=\dfrac{x-2}{x^5} = \dfrac{2z^2}{1-z^2} \cdot \left( \dfrac{1-z^2}{2} \right)^5 = z^2 \cdot \left( \dfrac{1-z^2}{2} \right)^4,$$
therefore,
$$\int \sqrt{\frac{x^2-2x}{x^6}}\,dx = 4\int{z \cdot \left( \dfrac{1-z^2}{2} \right)^2 \cdot \dfrac{z}{(1-z^2)^2}\,dz} = \int{z^2 \, dz = \ldots}$$